# How can I embed classical data into qubits from scratch, without using any quantum computing libraries/toolboxes?

Tags: embedding

I've read most of the available material on quantum embedding and none of it actually shows you how to embed classical data into a quantum form from scratch; the few that show you how to do it get away with `import qiskit`. Suppose I have a dataset that has a large amount of points, say, 10000, and each point has 35 dimensions (these numbers are arbitrary). How do I encode each point into a quantum state without using any libraries?

I know that there's several methods to embed data. For example, you can perform basis embedding, amplitude embedding, angle embedding, or do something else. Let's say I want to do amplitude embedding or angle embedding. How do I do this from scratch? I can of course reduce my data using classical algorithms like PCA to get it to lower dimensions, but what if I want to embed each point in 5 qubits? By my understanding, it is possible to embed a $2^5 = 32$ dimensional data point into 5 qubits using this method, but how do I get each qubit's superposed state?